# Implementing multiplication in $GF(2^{128})$ as defined for GCM

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes-gcm

I am trying to implement the algorithm 1 from https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf section 6.3.

My implementation doesn't seem to be giving correct answer. I compare my output with that given by [BouncyCastle's BasicGcmMultiplier](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/0259e7792f79f85c09668c4476d77bf7af5d7089/crypto/src/crypto/modes/gcm/BasicGcmMultiplier.cs#L25C26-L25C26) and results don't match.

I am looking for help to fix my implementation as I am unable to see what's wrong.

Here's my implementation in C#. The `gf_mul_be` method assumes that the byte array parameters are in big-endian order. Each byte array is 16 bytes long.

Example input and output:

- a = `acbef20579b4b8ebce889bac8732dad7`
- b = `ed95f8e164bf3213febc740f0bd9c4af`
- expected output = `4DB870D37CB75FCB46097C36230D1612`
- my output = `B57DEFF66E5E0AC75DA46B601ED12E49`

```cs
private static byte[] gf_mul_be(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    var V = new byte[16];
    b.CopyTo(V, 0);

    var Z = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0, 16).ToArray();   // 0^128

    var X = new byte[16];
    a.CopyTo(X, 0);

    for (var i = 127; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var j = i / 8;
        var k = i % 8;
        var xi = (X[j] >> (8-k-1)) & 1;
        if (xi == 1)
        {
            Z = Z.Zip(V, (z, v) => (byte)(z ^ v)).ToArray();    // Z XOR V
        }

        var lsbV = V[0] & 0x80; // LSBn is the rightmost n bits from LE bit representation as per spec; so for our BE representation, it's the leftmost
        LeftShiftByteArray(V);  // left-shift because we have the bitstring is reverse order (MSB first)
        if (lsbV != 0)
        {
            V[15] ^= 0x87; // bit pattern 1000 0111 in last byte
        }
    }

    return Z;
}

private static void LeftShiftByteArray(byte[] bytes)    // assumes bytes are in BE order
{
    var carry = 0;
    for (var l = bytes.Length - 1; l >= 0; l--)
    {
        var byteCopy = bytes[l];
        bytes[l] = (byte)(bytes[l] << 1);
        if (carry == 1)
        {
            bytes[l] = (byte)(bytes[l] | 0x01);
        }
        carry = (byteCopy & 0x80) >> 7;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation differs in some points from the specification in the linked document. I have fixed these discrepancies in the following code and aligned the code to the specification (see [NIST SP 800-38D](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf), sec. *6.3 Multiplication Operation Blocks*):

```cs
private static byte[] gf_mul_be_fixed(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    var V = new byte[16];
    b.CopyTo(V, 0);

    var Z = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0, 16).ToArray();   

    var X = new byte[16];
    a.CopyTo(X, 0);

    for (var i = 0; i < 128; i++)   // Change 1: reverse
    {
        var j = i / 8;
        var k = i % 8;
        var xi = (X[j] >> (8 - k - 1)) & 1;
        if (xi == 1)
        {
            Z = Z.Zip(V, (z, v) => (byte)(z ^ v)).ToArray();    
        }

        var lsbV = V[15] & 0x01;    // Change 2: use LSB1(V)
        RightShiftByteArray(V);     // Change 3: right shift bits
        if (lsbV != 0)
        {
            V[0] ^= 0xe1;           // Change 4: use MSB8(V) for XORing with R = b11100001 00000000 ... = 0xE100...
        }
    }
    return Z;
}
```

The changes are marked and described in the code. The implementation uses the following method, based on your implementation, for a right shift of the bits:

```cs
private static void RightShiftByteArray(byte[] bytes)   
{
    var carry = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        var byteCopy = bytes[i];
        bytes[i] = (byte)(bytes[i] >> 1);
        if (carry == 1)
        {
            bytes[i] = (byte)(bytes[i] | 0x80);
        }
        carry = (byteCopy & 0x01);
    }
}
```

If this code is executed:

```cs
byte[] a = Convert.FromHexString("acbef20579b4b8ebce889bac8732dad7");
byte[] b = Convert.FromHexString("ed95f8e164bf3213febc740f0bd9c4af");
byte[] c = gf_mul_be_fixed(a, b);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToHexString(c)); // 4DB870D37CB75FCB46097C36230D1612
```

the expected result *4DB870D37CB75FCB46097C36230D1612* is obtained in accordance with the implementation from BouncyCastle.

---

It is not clear to me why you deviate from the specification in your implementation. From the comments in your code I can guess you assume the algorithm requires data in the little endian order.
However, this is not the case if you read the specification carefully. There the term "*little endian*" is mentioned only once and refers to "*the convention for interpreting strings as polynomials*" and not to the byte order of the data.
The BouncyCastle implementation and thus also the *fixed* implementation interpret the data in big endian order in accordance with the definition from [chapter 6.1](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf) of the document (most significant bit = left-most bit and least significant bit = right most bit), which can be verified with respect to your implementation by a successive output of the `xi`.

---

Note that your original implementation can be kept if in the input arrays and the output array the order of the bits is inverted:

```cs
byte[] aRev = ReverseAllBits(a);
byte[] bRev = ReverseAllBits(b);
byte[] cRev = ReverseAllBits(gf_mul_be(aRev, bRev));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToHexString(cRev)); // 4DB870D37CB75FCB46097C36230D1612
```

with

```cs
private static byte[] ReverseAllBits(byte[] input)
{
    BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(input);
    Reverse(bitArray);
    byte[] reversed = new byte[input.Length];
    bitArray.CopyTo(reversed, 0);
    return reversed;
}

// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791224/9014097
public static void Reverse(BitArray array)
{
    int length = array.Length;
    int mid = (length / 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++)
    {
        bool bit = array[i];
        array[i] = array[length - i - 1];
        array[length - i - 1] = bit;
    }
}
```

This ultimately means that with your changes you have adapted the specified logic to an inverted bit sequence of the input and output data.

---

Here is an alternative implementation that uses the `System.Numerics.BigInteger` data type. This implementation is relatively compact, because the right-shift and xor operator from `BigInteger` can be used, and therefore perhaps easier to comprehend. However, I can't say much about the performance (which may be worse):

```cs
byte[] a = Convert.FromHexString("acbef20579b4b8ebce889bac8732dad7");
byte[] b = Convert.FromHexString("ed95f8e164bf3213febc740f0bd9c4af");
byte[] cBI2 = gf_mul_be_BI(a, b);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToHexString(cBI2)); // 4DB870D37CB75FCB46097C36230D1612

private static byte[] gf_mul_be_BI(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    BigInteger X = new BigInteger(a, true, true);
    BigInteger Y = new BigInteger(b, true, true);
    BigInteger R = new BigInteger(new byte[] { 0xe1 }, true, true) << 120;
    BigInteger z_i = BigInteger.Zero;
    BigInteger v_i = Y;
    for (byte i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        BigInteger x_i = X & (BigInteger.One << (127 - i));
        BigInteger z_i_1 = x_i == BigInteger.Zero ? z_i : z_i ^ v_i;
        BigInteger v_i_1 = (v_i % 2 == 0) ? v_i >> 1 : v_i >> 1 ^ R;
        z_i = z_i_1;
        v_i = v_i_1;
    }
    return z_i.ToByteArray(true, true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Topaco. Indeed I thought the spec wants me to consider that the bitstring is little-endian. It was not clear but I was trying to stick to a consistent interpretation which I thought was likely.